# MYSQL - create single record out of similar rows, chose values of greatest length for most columns

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, similarity

Here is my case, I have a database table with below fields:

```
name
place_code
email
phone
address
details
estd
others
```

and example data

[image]

If you look at the above example table, first three records are talking about `xyz` and place code `1020`.

I want to create a single record for these three records based on

```
substring(name,1,4) 
place_code
```

(I am lucky here for all the similar records satisfies this condition and unique in the table.)

For the other columns which record column length has max. For example again for the above 3 records email should be test@te.com, phone should be 657890 and details should be "testdetails".

This should be done for all the table. (Some has single records and some has max 10 records.)

Any help on query that helps me to get the desired result?

**Answer**

Some one posted the below answer and deleted it . But that looks a good solution

```
SELECT max(name),
       place_code,
       max(email),
       max(phone),
       max(address),
       max(details),
       max(estd),
       max(others)
FROM table_x
GROUP BY substring(name,1,4),place_code
```

Please let me know if you guys see any issues in it ?

Thank You all

Kiran

Comment: Does this blog post help you any?  http://johniekarr.blogspot.com/2011/08/pushing-multiple-results-into-one.html  Edit: I wrote it for SQL Server 2008, and I just realized you are using MySql, so I don't know if it will help or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT max(name),
       place_code,
       max(email),
       max(phone),
       max(address),
       max(details),
       max(estd),
       max(others)
FROM table_x
GROUP BY substring(name,1,4),place_code
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the awesome GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function.

```
SELECT place_code, 
       substring(name,1,4) name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(email), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(Phone), 
       GROUP_CONCAT(details)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY place_code, substring(name,1,4)
```

It has options allowing you to control things like the order of items in the string and the separators.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: @Ollie_Jones, But this will either exlude or group concate the fields  together for example your query will result `phone: excluded` for all rows, `details: test,testdetails` for `xyz` and null for other rows.

Comment: thanks @Ollie Jones - Please find the answer I posted in the question and let me know if you see any issues with it ..I used your answer for my some problem :) . Thank you again for your time and quick response .

Comment: What you have looks good, as long as you're happy with the MAX function to select the appropriate row from your details column.  I misunderstood your question; I thought you were wanting all the items from the details column.

Comment: Thank You @Ollie_Jones for your help